# How to place in center if two images

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have created [this](http://www.stavarov-ubytovna.cz) website. And now, I would like to center text on those two images in header. Relevant code is here

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="css/title578145459.png" class="headerImage left"/>
    <img src="css/title756941752.png" class="headerImage right"/>
    <span class="headerText">Ubytovna Stavařov Přerov</span>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.headerImage {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 190px;
    text-align: center;    
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.headerText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    color: yellow;
    font: normal 3em sling;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

I tried to set different values to `top` and `bottom` attributes, also I've tried to set `padding` and `margin` but neither of these have worked.

Comment: Center how ? Vertical, horizontal ? It's already centered horizontal but you can't see it because it's behind your images because of the `z-index:-1`. Change it to `z-index:10` and you'll see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your z-index on .headerText should be positive.  Using Chrome dev tools I was able to see the text using this:

```
.headerText {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 0px;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.headerText {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
z-index: 1;
}
```